# ajax call returning different datatypes?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax call:

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/RBA/Tools/_Actions")',
                data: $("#actionForm").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;

                    $("#DetailsEdit").removeClass('zoomInDown');
                    $("#DetailsEdit").addClass('flipInX');

                    $("#DetailsRefresh").html(response);
                    $("#actionPlaceholder").hide();

                    $("#dashSpinner").hide();

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    debugger;

                    $("#dashSpinner").hide();
                    swal({
                        title: "Error",
                        text: response.responseText,
                        type: "error",
                        showConfirmButton: true
                    });

                }

            });
```

I am having a problem with the error portion as it is returning html to me. When I run the MVC on my local machine, I am getting the error message displayed properly in a pop up box. When I deploy the application to another server, I am getting some lengthy html message which is really awkward. How do I fix this issue?

Here is my catch exception block of the controller that this ajax call is calling:

```
            catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e);

            if (e.Message.Contains("Is not a valid cause category."))
                error = "The selected category is not a valid category. Please choose another category.";
            else
                error = "You cannot take this type of action.";

            Response.StatusCode = 500;

            return Json(error);
        }
```

I know that my dataType in the ajax call is listed as html and I need the ajax call to return html when it is successful so that it can bring up another view. But in my error, I want to get a string so it can display the message to the sweetalert box. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The production IIS may be configured to hide error details triggered by the Status 500. The page would be the Yellow Page of Death html. BadRequest 400 might be a more appropriate response.

Comment: Remove `dataType: "html",` option - jQuery will infer it based on the MIME type of the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, error);
```

This will return a `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` result with your error message as the response body.

It may be necessary to include the following line of code to tell IIS to let you return 500:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true
```

Comment: what library does this belong to ?
Context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true

Comment: It doesn't belong to a library.  That is ASP.Net MVC code.

Comment: when i type that code in controller, it is asking me which library i want to reference : Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts, Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Context, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context

Comment: `Context` is a property on MVC controllers.  It isn't a namespace.

Comment: My mistake.  `Context` is a property on action filters.  Just remove `Context.` from my code.  `Response` is a property on your controller.